bad timestamp after insert command in influxdb
I am trying to write historical data with timestamp directly to influxdb.
Environment:

influxdb 1.6.3

How to reproduce:
insert command into influx console
INSERT test1,host=server1.hostname,read_ops=0 read_bytes=0 read_latency=0 write_ops=0 write_bytes=0 metadata_latency=0 ram_cache_hit=0 ssd_cache_hit_ratio=0 1718115000

Result:
ERR:. bad_timestamp


the same error happens when I try to push the data via curl post with precision s

on the server also UTC timezone
